# How to fix vertical selection handles in a modified paragraph style in UITextView (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

> **This is the problem:**

[image]

> **What I have done?**

I have set a paragraph Style to this text:

```
 let titleParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 titleParagraphStyle.alignment = .natural
 titleParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 33

 let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: titleParagraphStyle]
```

This of course made the cursor to be **HUGE** all the time, so after this I overrided caretfor and all is OK until selection of the text:

```
override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        var original = super.caretRect(for: position)
        guard let isFont = self.font else { return original }
        original.size.height = isFont.pointSize - isFont.descender
        return original
    }
```

> **What I am missing here? How can I make the selection handles to be equal size than the text?**

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: @AaronZheng no in a relevant way, just inheritance from UITextView and just Storyboard for adding the view and linking to source

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are literally changing the spacing attribute of your text which, in no way is possible to change the selecting cursor's size. What you can do is just programmatically make spacing in the `textDidChange` when you detect that the `yourTextField.attributedText?.size().width` passes a certain distance. I presume that you aren't copying and pasting, so just that will work. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: I don’t understand your answer, tried to modify typingAttributes if text is selected but nothing happened

Comment: I saw that you updated your answer, but to be clear, I’m missing some steps, what can define that certain distance? and if setting paragraph spacing is not correct, what will be?